# CSS - Inline element margin problems for page divider

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following page divider:

[image]

But, I'm ending up with this:

[image]

Obviously the yellow is just to tell me where the tops and bottom are (should be white), and I seem to be getting this unwanted top and bottom margin. I've tried a few methods including `display:inline-block`, `display:inline`, `margin-top:-2px` but lost what I've tried and what I haven't. The `span` was originally a `div` but this was one of the many things I changed trying.

This is my last attempt:

```
<style>
.pageDivider {
    margin: 30px 0;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.pageDivider .inner {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
    background: yellow;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
}
</style>

<div class="pageDivider"><span class="inner">SHARE</span></div>
```

Any clues on how to do this the proper way?

Comment: Maybe you should not set line-height and font-size randomly?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot delete my question, so I will share the solution I have just found which works really, really nicely - I hope it helps others.

> > [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u4cday93/)

```
h6.pageDivider {
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 40px 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #555;
}
h6.pageDivider:before,
h6.pageDivider:after {
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
h6.pageDivider:before {
    right: 30px;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
h6.pageDivider:after {
    left: 30px;
    margin-right: -50%;
}

<h6 class="pageDivider">HELLO WORLD</h6>
```

Answer (score -1):

your answer is ....

```css
.pageDivider {
    margin: 30px 0;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.pageDivider .inner {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:2.5px 20px !important;
    background: yellow;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageDivider"><span class="inner">SHARE</span></div>
```

Comment: Just ran the code snippet and it produces the same thing I did, a yellow block with an unwanted top and bottom margin!

Comment: Why would two people upvote an incorrect answer!!? Doesn't make sense.